# How to add values on array object

Tags: array, push

How can I add values in an array from the same object.

Sample structure of the array should be.

CountryName: USA
City : Florida, Texas, California

CountryName: UK
City: Scotland, Wales

I want to achieve that by using a loop after getting the result from the soql query.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't you want a `Map<String, List<Strings>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a `Map<String, List<String>>`  I'm not too sure what you're trying to do though..

```
Map<String, List<String>> countryToStateMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();

for(Country__c country : [Select ID, State__c, Country__c FROM Country__c])
{
    if(countryToStateMap.containsKey(country.Country__c))
    {
        countryToStateMap.get(country.Country__c).add(country.State__c);
    }
    else
    {
        countryToStateMap.put(country.Country__c, new List<String>{country.State__c});
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @EricSSH, just to add how can I use the Id to pass as parameter when the user click the State?

Comment: You should open another question